# Is there a way to add a title for Kibana Data Table visualization?

Tags: kibana, kibana-6

I have a created a Data Table with Kibana 6.4 showing daily SLA status to be included in a dashboard.
However I need to add a title to that Data Table (To be added above the table) but i cannot find any option to do that.

Can someone help me with adding a title to this table?

Comment: Please clarify your **specific problem** or **add additional details** to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. ***But*** don't you think that the best option would be to add a markdown element on top?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can understand from you problem .

In order to add a title over your Data Table , **you can save the name of your Data Table with the specific title you want and in Dashboard it will show above your Data Table Visualization.**